# Separate TypeScript config for NodeJS and frontend application in same project

Tags: node.js, typescript

As you know, NodeJS is not just the server language but also the tool of the routine automation for the frontend developers (e. g. `gulp` ans `webpack` are NodeJS utilities). I need TypeScript for both NodeJS (used by [gulpfile.ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulpfile.ts), for example) and for the frontend application built by Webpack, but in same project. In the general case, `tsconfig.json` for the Webpack application and for the NodeJS must not be same. How I can split TypeScript configuration?

Comment: You can create as many different `tsconfig.json`-like files as you need.  (If you name them like `tsconfig.foo.json` or `tsconfig-foo.json`, then Visual Studio Code will give you completions based on the `tsconfig.json` schema.)  Then the only problem is getting each tool you use (`tsc`, `tslint`, ...) to use the correct configuration file; hopefully each tool has an option to specify the file.  Try this and let me know if you run into a specific obstacle.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen, Thank you for the advice! ... I'll try.